# Need to change layout of Excel file to duplicate row and copy values in certain condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need an expert's help on this. I suppose I need VBA or complex formulas.

I'm trying to separate a row to multiple rows only if certain columns are populated.

Current situation:

[image]

Desired new layout:

[image]

The column locations are identical to what I have in my file - the only difference is that I have thousands of records like this.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is the Question?

Comment: I'll try to clarify the question - I've tried creating a VB script for this, but it's not working as expected. So it looks like I'm no good at this - question is if someone can help write a correct script for this, that would achieve the new layout shown in the 2nd photo.